# Unity3d background

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get an image to be a background on my camera. It's one picture, it doesn't need to be repeated. It would be nice to have it stretch out when the resolution of the screen changes. I've found older tutorials that show how todo it in an older version of unity, like this one: [Link](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/9729/how-can-i-display-a-flat-background-2d-image-not-a.html)
However it seems that functionality is no longer in the newest version of Unity. Does anyone have any idea how to put a single picture as background?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

- Add a Canvas (UI --> Canvas) to your scene and set it's render mode to "Screen Space - Camera".
- Set the Canvas' Render Camera to your scenes main camera (i.e. the camera you render your 3D scene with... or the only camera in the scene ;) )
- make sure the Plane Distance of the Canvas is set to the far plane of your camera. So if your far clipping plane is set to 1000 set the Plane Distance to 1000 as well (or 999, if images in the canvas happen to be clipped away by the camera). If your Plane Distance is lower than the far clipping plane of your camera, objects behind the Plane Distance will be occluded by Images on the canvas.
- Add an Image (UI --> Image) to the Canvas and set its anchor presets to strech on both axes.
- Set the Left, Top, Right and Bottom Parameters of the Image's Rect Transform to 0. Now the image should be full screen and adjust to any change in the aspect ratio.

That should do the trick :)